# how to set the z-index of two modal overlays in a stack wise in Angular?

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, overlay

Two modal in the same page, one over the other, but when i click on overlay the first modal opened gets closed. What i want is to open and close the modal by clicking on overlay as stack wise.

Comment: At least show what you have done. We don't even know what modal are you using.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/maahibhat88/ket8ysd6/#

Answer (score 1):

```
when you open a modal the overlay gets created, so if you have two modal, when you 
open both one after the other, two overlays will be created, now if you are getting 
the above issue follow.

1. Open the modals in your component.ts via click method.
2. after writing the $("#yourmodal").modal('open'); 
   set the z-index manually.
   write $(".modal-overlay:eq(1)").css( "z-index", "1018");
3. Check you modal overlays z-index and set according to your need.
```

Hope you' like it.

Example here at [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/maahibhat88/ket8ysd6/#&togetherjs=9uwUKEPRoE)